# When do you need to create a seperate xib for your controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Do you need to create a seperate xib for a table view controller?

For example I have a table view controller that I'm creating in xcode, file new (.h and .m) will I need to create a xib for it as well? I'm setting my table view controller as the root view controller for a navigation controller.

Basically I'm not sure if you always need a controller + view + xib for every view you have or the xib is optional if you don't need to drag subviews to it in IB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XIB is optional for any `UIViewController` - it just provides a convenient way to setup your view hierarchy visually, rather than in code. If you don't use a XIB, use `-[UIViewController loadView]` to setup your `UIViewController`'s `.view` property.